# Getting row data from invisible row in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

How can I get data from a row that's not in the current page, knowing its row id?
The grid has `datatype:"json"`

I tried using

```
$('#grid').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
```

but only works for visible rows (rows in the current page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I solved it (with loadonce:false), not sure if it's the best sollution...seems a bit of an overkill. I noticed that rows' ids had the same value as the GRID_ID column of my grid ( not sure why either). Anyway, it still may help somebody, so here it is:

Let's say that I have an array with some row ids that not all of them are in the current page

```
//Get all data
var allHugeData = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');

//Get rows' ids length
var count = ids.length;

//I will store the data in this array
var selRowsInAllPages = new Array();     

//Keep the data of these rows in selRowsInAllPages array
for(var x=0;x<allHugeData.length;x++){
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
        if(allHugeData[x].GRID_ID==ids[i]){
            selRowsInAllPages.push(allHugeData[x]);     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you use `datatype: "local"`. In the case you can use `getLocalRow`:

```js
var rowData = $('#grid').jqGrid ('getLocalRow', rowId);
```

Comment: Thanks but it's datatype:"json" so the code above returns 'false'.

Comment: @CoffeeCode: If you use `loadonce: true` then one can use `getLocalRow` too. If you use `datatype: "json"` *without* `loadonce: true` then jqGrid have only the current page you can't get the information from jqGrid. In the case you have to get the information from the server.